# Unable to comment as a new member - what about unclear questions?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I'm a pretty new member here, for answering at least. I'm trying to help people out as much as I can, but I seem to run into the issue that my only way of communicating with the OP is through a real 'answer'.

If I read the 'how to post a good answer' rules, it says you should not ask for clarification or more information in an answer. This creates a problem when dealing with unclear questions, or when more information is needed.

Should I just ask for more information in an 'answer', or is that frowned upon by the community?

Comment: Highly frowned upon and will only hurt you. The rep minimum kind of sucks but is unfortunately necessary. Wait until you have the rep to comment. Until then, post good, quality questions and answers and you will be to 50 in no time

Comment: Allright. Guess i'll just have to be patient, and try to help out without commenting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thank you for reading [why questions get deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before giving a non-answer as an answer. You have saved yourself and others some grief.

Comment: @L7Lynx besides asking good questions and writing good answers, you can also gain reputation by making good edits to posts (+2 rep for every good edit). You'd only need to make 25 good edits to any post, so you also have that option to contribute to the community, if you want to earn the privilege of commenting on any post.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it is highly frowned upon. In fact, such answers are flagged and removed by the community. Unfortunately, there's no other way to request clarification from the OP. You need to wait until you have the [Comment privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). But this shouldn't take long — it only takes a few upvotes to make 50. Continue contributing positively towards the community and you'll reach there in no time!

See also: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Oh damn. Didn't think it would be such a frequently asked question. Didn't really find anything. Seems like I even posted in the wrong meta-website. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: @L7Lynx You posted to the right site. It's just that up until very recently SO was using an external meta site as its meta. The powers that be have made it clear that if you have any concerns with how SO is run you can post your question *here*. If anything needs to be moved to the global Stack Exchange meta, they'll move it themselves.

Comment: @AmalMurali you should mention that making good edits to existing posts is also an option for earning more rep (+2 rep for every good edit).

Comment: @Cupcake: It may have a negative impact if new users consider "suggested edits" as a way to earn reputation. Anyhow, this user now has more than 50 rep now, so it shouldn't matter anymore.

Comment: @AmalMurali I disagree, making good edits to existing posts is a perfectly valid and legitimate way to earn reputation. There's even an upvoted answer that supports this idea: [see Sam Saffron's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127538/163250).

Comment: @Cupcake: I didn't say it isn't legitimate. But new users are known to make stupid suggestions (like backtick abuse, adding unrelated tags etc.). Users who suggest edits at their own will are okay, but if we also encourage new users to use suggested edits as a way to increase rep, they might (just a personal opinion) misuse it.

Comment: @AmalMurali but that's why edits by new users ***are reviewed***.

Comment: @Cupcake: Then we are wasting the time of 3 reviewers. If you search Meta, I'm sure you can find many posts discussing robo-reviewers approving stupid suggested edits. Essentially, this means **bad edits** will get approved. On the other hand, it takes only 5 upvotes on answers to gain 50 reputation points.

Comment: I have no proof of this, but I would like to imagine that the number of new users with low rep *reading meta.SO* who would go on to use that suggestion for evil, is low, while the number of such new users who would go on to get 50 rep and be able to participate fully (who might otherwise say screw it, because let's face it, using SO without the ability to comment kinda sucks) is much larger. Yes, the internet is full of idiots/trolls/idiotic trolls, but how many of them are reading meta?

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you are restricted from posting a comment when you have less than 50 reputation points. The reasoning behind the limitation can be summarized like this:

- New users are far more likely to post bad comments than other users
- Comments typically add less value to the community than answers
- Comments are difficult to moderate

While these are valid arguments, whoever came up with this clearly didn't think it through... If I got a penny for every time I've seen a new user post an answer like `This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet`, I'd be rich. Usually, this involves cases where additional info is asked to be able to write down a proper answer.

Not only does the inability for new users to comment encourage them to post comments as answers due to the lack of alternatives, the subsequent (often aggressive) downvoting and/or deleting of such poor answers only discourages well-meaning new users from participating in this community altogether.

And no, posting an answer based on insufficient or wrongly interpreted information is not a valid alternative. I've seen many answers getting downvoted for that as well, which has pretty much the same effect on well-meaning new users.

The only thing I can recommend for those who do not have enough reputation points to comment on a question, is to ignore any questions that you cannot answer without additional information. It sucks, but I can't think of any alternative approach that is not frowned upon on Stack Overflow!