# Why can't new users post comments on another users question?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I've been trying to answer some questions on SO, but I always have to ask the person who made the question for more details, but I can't because new users can't.

My question is, why aren't new users allowed to post comments, if they can answer the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to comment as a new member - what about unclear questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250977/unable-to-comment-as-a-new-member-what-about-unclear-questions) - also relevant: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 2):

There is a small reputation barrier erected for new users as a spam prevention mechanism.

If you're wondering why answers have no such rep barrier, it's because:

1. Stack Exchange is about getting answers, not writing comments, and
2. We have better spam control tools for answers.

Don't even think about posting that comment as an answer.  You'll have 50 reputation soon enough, and then the system will trust you to use comments responsibly.

Comment: Why not apply those spam filters on comments too?sometimes you really need to ask the user before answering.

Comment: What spam filters?  Moderation tools, the same ones we use to do ordinary moderation.  And Captchas.  They don't exist for comments.

Comment: I mean spam control tools,sorry. Why not add those tools for comments too?or make that barrier lower,25 would be enough IMO.

Comment: One or two good answers will give you enough rep to post comments, @Lucas

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to suggest something,as I don't find how it is right now the best way.

Comment: At 28 rep, you're more than halfway there already.

Answer (score 1):

The 50 reputation restriction is there to prevent spammers posting spam as comments.

Comments are second class entities on Stack Exchange and aren't subject to the same checks and reviews as questions and answers. This makes it harder to spot and deal with spam or other inappropriate comments.

To make it harder for people to spam via the comments we put in the requirement that you need to have some real activity on the site. For the most part it works, but there is this issue of new users like yourself wanting to help but can't.

The only solution (at the moment) is to find something you *can* answer without requiring more information and earn the 50 points needed.

Comment: Or make 25 good suggested edits.