# Does Stack Overflow having 50 reputation for commenting make sense?

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow seems to frustrate me every time when it has the comment link, downvote buttons and when clicking, it gives the annoying "you don't have enough reputation". Why oh why?

Why doesn't Stack Overflow just hide those buttons if I don't have that much reputation? The interface on the face does not communicate that that functionality will not be available when clicking on it.

It also does an absolute terrible job of telling me what I need to do to activate the functionality. How does one even end up with 50 reputation points? It has absolute zero mention of it.

I have been a user of Stack Overflow for over an year. It's insane that it still blocks me out.

All I am trying to say is, Stack Overflow needs to do some user testing. You are alienating a ton of folks who want to contribute. I was on a question, and I wanted to make a comment on a more optimal solution. I would have paid money to get that stupid error go away and just let me make a damn comment.

Comment: "*How does one even end up with 50 reputation points. It has absolute zero mention of it.*" This is a Question and Answer site. You get reputation by providing good Questions or good Answers ("good" being defined as "what people upvote"). That's core functionality of the site. It's part of the "[Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)" you were supposed to take when you first joined. So it doesn't need to be mentioned every time you're told you don't have reputation for something.

Comment: I don't understand how you can be motivated enough to write this up, but not motivated enough to even look up *how* to earn 50 reputation.

Comment: While the suggestion of hiding the buttons is a good one, you've done a very poor job of stating your case by involving outrage in the tone of your post. Achieving 50 rep may seem difficult, but it's actually very easy and helps to prevent lots of spam and poor comments. Stick around in the community longer and you'll see some of the *massive* amount of poor content being moderated so that poignant questions can be given answers.

Comment: @Aaron3468 Plus one for referring to questions as "poignant".

Comment: Sigh.... Another "i dont really know why the site is built that way, BUT IT NEEDS TO CHANGE NOW". Take the time to learn and understand why the site is built the way it is. There are reasons why it functions the way it does

Comment: Duplicate of (likely the canonical question): *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)* (cross-site).

Comment: It never made any sense to me that you (1) are allowed to post answers, (2) are not allowed to post comments and (3) are left with no alternative way for asking additional information required to properly answer a question, since posting comments as answers is a big no-no on this site. Yes, it does make new users feel very unwelcome! Yes, it does chase away many of them! Yes, that totally sucks!! I'm afraid that's just something you have to live with, though. This issue has been pointed out at nauseam, and no one with the power to do so seems to want to fix it... Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @JohnSlegers - They likely require 50 rep to comment because only moderators (or the system) are capable of removing comments. Q&A can be handled by community moderation. There's no good reason to block new users from answering questions that don't require additional clarification.

Comment: @BSMP : If people are unable to comment, they should at least be given an alternate way of getting additional information from the person asking the question. By not being allowed to comment, many people feel forced to post their comments as an answer... which results in their answers getting first downvoted and then deleted... which in turn results in people getting frustrated and giving up on this website. I literally see this happening all the friggin' time!  Is that really the user experience SO is going for?

Comment: *they should at least be given an alternate way of getting additional information* @JohnSlegers I'd personally be willing to consider an idea for doing this, though that would need to be a separate feature request. But I don't think you're going to get a lot of sympathy by pointing out that the people leaving the site do so because they tried to game the system and failed.

Comment: @BSMP : How exactly is asking for someone to clarify their question (just so they're able to provide a proper answer) "gaming the system"?

Comment: @BSMP : See also eg. my answer to the question [**Unable to comment as a new member - what about unclear questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250977/unable-to-comment-as-a-new-member-what-about-unclear-questions/318121#318121) and Brad Larson's answer to the question [**How should one ask for clarification on a question if they can't yet comment?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment/258670#258670)

Comment: Using the answer field to post a comment, knowing that you don't have permission to post comments yet, is gaming the system. It's an attempt to cheat the privilege system.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, yes it does make sense - it's to stop new users who don't read the help articles such as [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from commenting all over the place.